# JPA cb.equal() not work in query.orderBy()

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I was implemented a method generates `Specification` to order a complex query like below:

```
/** Order base items with at least one allowed grandchild first. */
public static Specification<BaseEntity> order() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<BaseEntity, ChildEntity> children = root.join(BaseEntity_.children);
        Join<ChildEntity, GrandChildEntity> grandChildren = children.join(ChildEntity_.grandChildren);
        Path<StatusType> status = grandChildren.get(GrandChildEntry_.status);
        query.groupBy(root.get(BaseEntity_.seq));
        Expression<Boolean> hasAtLeastOneAllowed = cb.function(
                "bit_or", Boolean.class, cb.equal(status, StatusType.ALLOWED));
        query.orderBy(cb.desc(hasAtLeastOneAllowed));
        return cb.and();
    };
}
```

with my wish to correspond it to a `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT BASE.*
FROM BASE
    INNER JOIN CHILD ON BASE.id = CHILD.base_id
    INNER JOIN GRAND_CHILD ON CHILD.id = GRAND_CHILD.child_id
GROUP BY BASE.id
ORDER BY BIT_OR(GRAND_CHILD.status = "ALLOWED") DESC;
```

and I tested this query works well.

But `BaseRepository.findAll(spec)` raises a `NullPointerException` and hard to debug since detailed logics are wrapped by proxies and managed by Spring.

Ridiculously, below code **works well as expected**:

```
/** Order base items by earliest allowed date of its grandchildren. */
public static Specification<BaseEntity> order() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<BaseEntity, ChildEntity> children = root.join(BaseEntity_.children);
        Join<ChildEntity, GrandChildEntity> grandChildren = children.join(ChildEntity_.grandChildren);
        Path<LocalDate> allowedDate = grandChildren.get(GrandChildEntry_.allowed_date);
        query.groupBy(root.get(BaseEntity_.seq));
        Expression<LocalDate> minDateAllowed = cb.function(
                "min", LocalDate.class, allowedDate);
        query.orderBy(cb.asc(minDateAllowed));
        return cb.and();
    };
}
```

I think `cb.equal()` does not work properly in ordering chunk. Please let me know how can I fix the code. Thanks.

### Edit

`cb.equal()` is the cause of failure. It works when I use

```
cb.function("eq", Boolean.class, status, cb.literal(StatusType.ALLOWED.name()))
```

instead of

```
cb.equal(status, StatusType.ALLOWED)
```

with a custom `MySQL` function wraps `=` operator for strings

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION eq(s1 TEXT, s2 TEXT)
    RETURNS BIT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
        RETURN s1 = s2;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Why `cb.equal()` does not work within `query.orderBy()`? And how can I implement my code without creating custom `MySQL` functions?

Comment: `BIT_OR` is a MySQL function and I doubt that JPA knows anything about it.  You will probably have to use a raw query here or maybe a raw order by, if that would be possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tested `BIT_OR` works with `cb.function("bit_or", Boolean.class, status);`, not `cb.function("bit_or", Boolean.class, cb.equal(status, StatusType.ALLOWED));`. Also, `MIN` for dates works properly.

Comment: I upvoted your question, I don't know the API well enough to help further.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks XD